# How do I URL Encode a URL parameter that is itself a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Quick background -

I am making a jQuery ajax call to a service I wrote that returns a JSON response. The service accepts a web site URL (i.e. www.google.com, www.xyz.com/abc123). The format of the request is as follows:

```
http://www.mysite.com/[url]
```

... where [url] is a user provided URL (again, something like www.google.com/abc)

I need to URL encode the parameter, as mysite.com/www.google.com is giving me errors.

My problem is, all of the standard javascript encoding functionality does not actually encode the URL.

An example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.write("encodeURIComponent = " + encodeURIComponent("www.google.com") + "<br />");
document.write("encodeURI = " + encodeURI("www.google.com") + "<br />");
document.write("escape = " + escape("www.google.com"));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

... has the following output:

```
encodeURIComponent = www.google.com
encodeURI = www.google.com
escape = www.google.com
```

What is the proper way to achieve this using JavaScript/jQuery?

I don't think it's relevant, but just in case, this is a Rails 3.0.7 app.

EDIT FOR MORE DETAIL

If www.google.com is already URL encoded, and periods are fine in my URL (www.mysite.com/www.google.com), why am I getting this error?

From Chrome Dev Tools:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/s/www.google.com 404 (Not Found)
```

My jQuery snippet:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/s/" + encodeURI($("#txtURL").val()), function(data) {
        alert(data.result.url);
    });
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just do like ?id=[url]

Comment: `http://mysite.com/www.google.com` is a perfectly valid URL.

Comment: Please see my edit, added a bit more specifics to my problem!

Comment: re: Edit - you're getting a 404 because it's looking for a directory or file name called `www.google.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid URL:

```
http://mysite.com/s/www.google.com
```

I suspect that you're just running into the Rails `format` stuff (i.e. `.html` at the end of the URL sets the format to HTML, `.js` for JSON, ...) so you just need to fix your route to keep the format auto-detection from getting in the way:

```
map.connect '/s/:url', :requirements => { :url => /.*/ }, ...
```

or

```
match '/s/:url' => 'pancakes#house', :constraints => { :url => /.*/ }, ...
```

or whatever routing syntax you're using.

If you don't tell rails that the `:url` should match `/.*/` (i.e. anything at all), it will try to interpret the periods in the route as format specifiers, that will fail and Rails will 404 because it can't figure out how to route the URL.

Comment: Perfect! The last thing I suspect seems to always be the problem :) Much appreciated for helping me through this - :constraints did the trick

Comment: @Evan: Remember this when you need to put an email address in a route, that's where I hit it the first time :)

Answer (score 2):

URL encoding escapes characters that have a special meaning in the URL (like `/` and `?`) and/or aren't ASCII characters. `http://mysite.com/www.google.com` is a perfectly valid URL, there's nothing to escape. If you'd include the protocol as well, you'd get some escape-worthy characters:

```
encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com')
"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com"
```

If your server 404s on a request to `http://localhost:3000/s/www.google.com`, that means the URL isn't handled by the server. It doesn't mean that the URL is invalid.

Comment: Gotcha, I think this may be a problem with my Rails routing in that case - appreciate the help and insight!

Answer (score 1):

As mu said dots don't need to be encoded.
The jQuery-way for building a proper QUERY_STRING would be the use of `$.param()`

```
$.param({encodeURIComponent:'http://www.google.de'})
```