# How to get the url parameter from a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to get the url parameter like below.

```
http://localhost:3000/g/http://google.com
```

So, I set config/routes.rb like below

```
get '/g/:url' => "urls#show"
```

But I can't get params[:url] in the urls#show.

How can I get the parameter?

Comment: There already are a lot of questions about passing a url as a url parameter, try searching a bit more ;)

Comment: I got a question like this.Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804751/how-do-i-url-encode-a-url-parameter-that-is-itself-a-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I URL Encode a URL parameter that is itself a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804751/how-do-i-url-encode-a-url-parameter-that-is-itself-a-url)